# How to set user agent in osmdroid code?

Tags: android, dictionary, osmdroid

I am going to get started with Open Street Maps using osmdroid. A beginner tutorial found on their [github wiki](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library) says you have to set user agent to prevent from being banned by osm servers. The comment does not go beyond the tip on how to do this. So, the result of running the code is that I see nothing in the resulting map. There is only a map canvas and zoom controls, but nothing like a geographical point or something.
My activity code is as follows (using version 5.6.5 of the osmdroid library):

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MapView map = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        //important! set your user agent to prevent getting banned from the osm servers

        Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));

        map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);

        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        map.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        IMapController mapController = map.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(9);
        GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(48.8583, 2.2944);
        mapController.setCenter(startPoint);


    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Configuration.getInstance().load(this, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));
//        map.onResume(); //needed for compass, my location overlays, v6.0.0 and up
    }

    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
//        map.onPause();  //needed for compass, my location overlays, v6.0.0 and up
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

`Configuration.getInstance().load` will actually set it for you. You can override it and set it to whatever you want via   `Configuration.getInstance().setUserAgent`

I'll update the wiki to reflect

The explicit source that sets this is here
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/ae026862fe4666ab6c8d037b9e2f8805233c8ebf/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/config/DefaultConfigurationProvider.java#L306

Basically, it gets the apk's package name from the manifest and uses that (by default)